# "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code." - Not a single line of code was written that day

Tags: support, specific-question

I really need to ask this question on SO, but I'm not sure what's triggering the "code formatting" checker that is disabling my submission. I've cut sections out of the code that I think may be causing the issue, but to no avail.

> Hey StackOverflow, for the past 4 days I've been trying to integrate
>   Eclipse EE and Tomcat7 to no avail. I've tried the recommendations
>   posted in a variety of other SO threads.
>
> In terms of install configurations I've used the following methods:
>
> - apt-get install tomcat7
> - installation from .tar.gz source
>
> I'm running on a clean install, and had been trying on the old install
>   to get Eclipse EE to recognize a *running* or *stopped* Tomcat7
>   service (unsuccessful)
>
> > **Environment variables**
> >
> > **CATALINA_BASE:** /usr/share/tomcat7
> >
> > **CATALINA_HOME:** /usr/share/tomcat7
> >
> > **CATALINA_TMPDIR:** /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
> >
> > **JRE_HOME:** /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_07/jre
> >
> > **USING CLASSPATH:** /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
> >
> > **JAVA_HOME:** /usr/lib/jvm/java   The Tomcat7 service appears to be configured properly, upon navigating to *localhost:8080*, I'm greeted
> >     with "It works!", confirming a successful install. Any suggestions?
> >     I'm fresh out of ideas. **Is Ubuntu 12.04 on my hardware simply not
> >     compatible with a package in Eclipse EE that allows it to sync up with
> >     Tomcat7?**
>
> ---
>
> **Toggling the service on/off doesn't appear to make a discernible difference.**
>
> How can I link Tomcat7 to EclipseEE? Is it possible? Should I move to
>   GlassFish or JBoss? I need to have this set up ASAP. I'm already
>   losing too much time.

Comment: Given that you have posted this now, I assume the issue was resolved? I also don't think this counts as a bug.

Comment: Have you tried using `fixed formatting` for the environment variable names?  I bet that it sees capitals, underscores and colons and assumes it's some variety of programming language.

Answer (score -11):

Try using the <pre> tag around your code-like sections (CATALINA_BASE:.. etc)

Comment: Downvoters, did you _try_ using the `<pre>` tag before you downvoted?

Comment: The text clearly isn't code, and it is displayed properly with no html or markup, so the OP shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: @Servy This suggestion is intended to fix this instance of the problem for OP. If it does solve the problem, then vote it up and put a checkmark on it.

Comment: @The problem is that the message is indicating that there is unformatted code.  There is no code to format.  The fix is not to use code markup around text that isn't code (that would be harming the post, not fixing it), the fix is to change whatever automated process determines that there is unformatted code and "fix" it.

Comment: It's probably hard to "fix" this, because the posted config file information does look like a bunch of `case:` labels.  Is it worth "fixing" the problem?  The `<pre>` tag isn't necessarily code, and there's no harm in formatting this data with it.

Comment: I don't see how you could get case labels out of it, and wrapping this in `<pre>` tags would indeed cause harm; it would cause the markdown for the bold to be treated as astricks, rather than bolding the text.